# "IN" expression binding multiple values

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to migrate user data from old SQLite to new SQLite.

First, I query the id of all favorite content via

```
SELECT id FROM content WHERE favorite = 1
```

Then I kept all favorite content id in NSMutableArray like this

```
NSMutableArray *favContentIds = [NSMutableArray array];  
while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {  
    NSInteger favContentId = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);  
    [favContentIds addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:favContentId]];  
}
```

Now I want to bind favContentIds in update statement

```
UPDATE content SET favorite = 1 WHERE id IN ?
```

I tried sqlite3_bind_text but it doesn't work. Do I have to convert favContentIds to NSString with UTF8String?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing `UPDATE content SET favorite = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM content WHERE favorite = 1)` in a round about way?

Comment: @mu: I can't because it's different SQLite. I SELECT id FROM one SQLite and UPDATE data to another one.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Have you tried building an update like `IN (?,?,?,?,...)` (i.e. one `?` per value) and then individual integer binds for each placeholder? I don't see anything in the SQLite C API for binding a whole array.

Comment: I haven't try this yet. So if SQLite API doesn't support binding array then I need two for loop of favContentIds, first for make statement (?, ?, ..) and second for bind_int to each placeholder. I think this method should work, I'll try.